# Web app, android and ios. How to interface them all with a database

Tags: android, ios, database, e-commerce

I'm new to android and ios development. My question is pretty simple. I've got a basic ecommerce website and I need to create an app version of the website. I want to create two native apps. What's the best way to do it? How can I interact with the database on an android and ios app. (I wasn't able to find a complete answer on the internet, but if there's one please let me know and I will close this question immediately). Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You need to create web services. 
You can develop in java, PHP, etc. 
The web services will receive requests from the mobile, get the data from the database and then send a response to the mobile. The mobile APPs will never interact with the server database, they will only make request to the web services and get responses.
To this the most common is to make REST calls with JSON.

In Android you can use [Retrofit](http://square.github.io/retrofit/).
And in iOS you can use [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking).

A good PHP example of how to develop your REST and JSON service you can find [here](http://www.9lessons.info/2012/05/create-restful-services-api-in-php.html).

Comment: Thank you, i'm stating to understand how it works now

Answer (score 0):

You would need some API to access the data. You can use PHP, Java or C# to develop your own API's. The API will handle requests and return the required data. You Android client will connect to the API and perform Http requests. Check out this guide on how to perform Http requests: https://developer.android.com/training/volley/simple.html

You can also check this question for more info: I want to make a apps where people can upload their status,image or video what I need to know for this?

Comment: Thank you, i'm stating to understand how it works now